# Download a zip or a pdf doesn't work on IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, download

I'm stuck with an issue in my project. I have two buttons in my page, one to download a pdf and one to download a zip. These downloads work on every browser except IE8 (IE9 works).

In IE8, there's a message that said "To help protect your security, ...". When I click on "Download this file", the browser refresh the page and I lost everything I've done. But when I try again to download a file, the browser let me do it.

There's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

There's my code:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (IsPostBack)
        return;

    if (Request.QueryString["outputpdf"] == "1" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PdfReportFilePath))
    {
        OutputPdfFile(PdfReportFilePath);
        PdfReportFilePath = string.Empty;
        Response.End();
    }

    if (Request.QueryString["outputexport"] == "1" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RxMapSession.ExportedFilePath))
    {
        OutputExport(RxMapSession.ExportedFilePath);
        RxMapSession.ExportedFilePath = RxMapSession.ExportedFileName = string.Empty;
        Response.End();
    }

    initChart();
}

private void OutputExport(string exportedFilePath)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(exportedFilePath));
    Response.WriteFile(exportedFilePath);
}

private void OutputPdfFile(string reportFullPath)
{
    string fileName = reportFullPath.Split('\\').Last();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.WriteFile(reportFullPath);
    Response.End();
}
```

Do you have any ideas why I have this problem on IE8?

Comment: This is a client side "problem" with IE8 on XP. You can't do anything about it in your code. Some users will experience the problem as well.

Comment: I've tried this on Windows Server 2008. I don't know the OS of my customers.

Comment: The server might have "Internet Explorer Enhanced Security" enabled..

Comment: No, it's Off on the server

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Go to Tools → Internet Options
2. Go to Advanced tab
3. Check "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer".
4. Save settings and close all IE windows and restart IE.

OR

1. Go to Tools → Internet Options
2. Click the Security tab, and then click a security zone Trusted sites.
3. Click Sites.
4. The website should be shown in the Add this website to the zone field.
5. Click Add.
6. Click Close, and then click OK.
7. Close all IE windows and restart IE.

Comment: Sorry but none of these work. I tried the first then the second and both at the same time but it doesn't work. In addition, our customers can't change their security policy.

Comment: The Protected Mode is also Off.

Comment: I found a solution. When you put your website in the Trusted Sites, you have to put the level at Medium-Low. I left the level at Medium and it still prompt to download the files. At the Medium-Low level, the files are downloaded.

Thanks again for your answer.